# get latest date and compare it today

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table with a date column in it. I need to get the max date and then compare it today and see if it is earlier or later than getdate()

Below is how I did it. Is there a more concise way of putting it?

```
declare @maxDate datetime
declare @todayDate datetime

with firsttable as (
  select max(ColumnA) as MaxColumnA from tbl
  )
  select @maxDate = MaxColumnA from firsttable
  select @todayDate = GETDATE()
  if (@maxDate > @todayDate)
  begin
    select 'variable date is later than today' 
  end
  else
  begin
    select 'variable date is earlier than today'
  end
```

[See my SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8449/24)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you just do it with "if exists" like this?

```
if exists (select 1 from tbl where ColumnA > getdate()) begin
   select 'variable date is later than today' 
end else begin
    select 'variable date is earlier than today'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33710/2)

try:

```
select case when cast(max(date1)  as date)>cast(getdate() as date) 
then 'variable date is later than today' else 'variable date is earlier than 
today' end from tab1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
declare @tbl TABLE 
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,Date DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    Date
)
VALUES ('3/26/2015'),('3/26/2025')

SELECT TOP 1
    CASE 
        WHEN Date > GETDATE() THEN 'variable date is later than today'
        ELSE 'variable date is earlier than today'
    END
FROM 
    @tbl
ORDER BY 
    Date DESC
```